# Are there recognized strategies to get the adjectives associated with a person or a place in NLP (or the general impression of a person or a place)?

Tags: nlp, pos-tagger

I am acquainted with part of speach tags (POS-tag), but even with this metodology does not seem trivial to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One could say that there are 2 components in the problem statement.

1. The first component is to identify a person or place from the text.
2. The second component is to then identify the adjective corresponding to that person or place.

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61372354/extracting-related-date-and-location-from-a-sentence/61377290#61377290) helps in solving the first component mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you! Name entity recognition like Pos-tag is the easy part, since it well known partially solved problem. The difficulty is exactly the second part.